# How to export value from then()?

Tags: node.js

I want to include the following js in a module:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const got = require('got');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;

const vgmUrl = 'https://example.com/somehtml.html';


got(vgmUrl).then(response => {
    var dom = new JSDOM(response.body);
    var textContent = dom.window.document.getElementById("__NEXT_DATA__").textContent;
    var JSONData = JSON.parse(textContent);
    return JSONData.props.pageProps.text.vaccinaties.data.kpi_total.tab_total_estimated.value;
}).then(out => {
    //console.log(out);
    module.exports = out;
});
```

When I include it using:

```
const module = require('./module.js');
```

and then with `console.log(module);` it returns an empty object `{}`.

How can I export the value of the variable 'out' inside the last `then()` ?

Comment: Why do you need to export it like so? Why not just export the Promise, import it where you need it and just do another `.then()` on the imported Promise? EDIT: you can keep your current file as it is. After you import it and call `.then()` the argument will be your return value (`JSON.props...` and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js build on top of asynchronous calls. In your case I would do something like this.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const got = require('got');
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const {JSDOM} = jsdom;

const vgmUrl = 'https://example.com/somehtml.html';

let outData = null;

const requestsCallbacks = [];


got(vgmUrl).then(response => {
    var dom = new JSDOM(response.body);
    var textContent = dom.window.document.getElementById("__NEXT_DATA__").textContent;
    var JSONData = JSON.parse(textContent);
    return         JSONData.props.pageProps.text.vaccinaties.data.kpi_total.tab_total_estimated.value;
}).then(out => {
    //console.log(out);
    outData = out;
    requestsCallbacks.forEach(cb => cb(out));
});

module.exports = () => {

    // If out data is already available just return it
    if (outData) {    
        return outData;
    }

    // Store all requests to return outData when available
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        requestsCallbacks.push(resolve);
    });

}
```

When you need to use it:

```
const module = require('./module.js');
async function doSomething() {
   const data = await module();
}
```

Comment: How can I use the `data` of the function `doSomething()`? When I add `return data` to the `doSomething()` it returns  `Promise { <pending> }`. Please forgive me, I am a total noob.

Comment: The easiest way is to declare "async" function and "await" until promise return value ( like in my example ).

Comment: Here is a good explanation for how async/await works. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem before and found out that I cannot export a 'real' object if inside a module has async function, I cannot using await in the top level of module, and I cannot export inside a function like you did too. So the solution comes with the nature of javascript. You have to export a promise of your object (or your async function) like Georgi B. Nikolov mentions in the comment.